# cdk synth --no-staging generates invalid template.yaml file resulting in failing to parse template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Running `cdk synth --no-staging` resulting in the following invalid template.yaml file:

```
URL  https://${Token[TOKEN.320]}.execute-api..amazonaws.com/local
Resources:
  genericTableEEB4DDB6:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: PK
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: SK
          KeyType: RANGE
```

I do not know the reason it generates the first, which gives the following error:

```
Error: Failed to parse template: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<unicode string>", line 2, column 10:
    Resources:
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the interesting parts of the CDK code that creates this template?

Answer (score 0):

There was a `console.log()` that it was printing the following line `URL  https://${Token[TOKEN.320]}.execute-api..amazonaws.com/local`.

Removing it, solved the issue.